# Launching multiple .NET Core web sites from a single hub site

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, blazor

I have 2 independent websites in Azure and have another website as hub site for launching these 2 web sites using menus like below. Both sites should be loading under hub site on selecting menu. `Do we need to use IFrame for this or any one has a better suggestion?` All web sites are Blazor based.

[image]

Comment: iFrame, standard links, or let JS/blazor do it.  Those are your options... but you should consider security implications if the links need to pass along cookies or any login state.

Comment: I tried to load google site in an IFrame and now XFrame error has thrown as "chromewebdata/:1 Refused to display 'google.com' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.". . I hope this X-Frame header settings of the external sites can't be overriden considering security.... Isn't it?

Comment: You can know that your site is being displayed in an iframe... beyond x-frame-options you can know if it's not the parent of the DOM.... all these things rely on the browser though.  You should assume that credentials can still be stolen if not handled correctly.  Avoid cross-site/cross-domain scripting.